# PHP switch case + PDO Update DB

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, pdo

I am sending data to a php file using AngularJS on ng-click. I have 2 buttons and I am trying to send it to the same php file to insert into the db using switch case but it is not updating the db.

How can I fix my php?

insert.php

```
<?php 

  include_once('conn.php');

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  switch($data){

  case 'getvou':    
    $vou = $data->getvou;
    $sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE audiencia SET vou = '".$vou."'");
    $mysqli->close();
    break;

  case 'getnaovou':
    $naovou = $data->getnaovou;
    $sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE audiencia SET nao_vou = '".$naovou."'");
    $mysqli->close();
    break;
  }

?>
```

script.js

```
$scope.add_vou = function(){ 

    $scope.vou += 1;

    $http.post("http://localhost/insert-audiencia.php", {'getvou': $scope.vou}).then(function(resp){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
        console.log(resp); 
    });
}

$scope.add_nao_vou = function(){ 

    $scope.nao_vou += 1;

    $http.post("http://localhost/insert-audiencia.php", {'getnaovou': $scope.nao_vou}).then(function(resp){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
        console.log(resp); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` will be a JSON object, which will not equal either of those strings, so no `case` will be matched in your `switch`.

With the way you're currently sending the data, you need to be checking instead to see if the JSON object has a property.

```
if (property_exists($data, 'getvou')) {
    // one query
} elseif (property_exists($data, 'getnaovou')) {
    // other query
}
```

`isset($data->getvou)` etc. will also work for this.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thanks a lot